# How to draw transparent graphics using Direct2D

Tags: c++, direct2d

```
//ID2D1DCRenderTarget* pDCRT；
//ID2D1SolidColorBrush* pBrush;
 
pDCRT->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0, 1, 0.5f)));
 
D2D1_ELLIPSE pe1 = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(200, 200), 150, 150); 
D2D1_ELLIPSE pe2 = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(350, 200), 150, 150);
 
pDCRT->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(1, 0, 0, 1), &pBrush);    
pDCRT->FillEllipse(pe1, pBrush); 
     
pDCRT->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0, 1, 0, 0.5f), &pBrush);       
pDCRT->FillEllipse(pe2, pBrush);
```

[image: image description]

This is a window that supports transparency. The left circle is opaque and the right circle is translucent. The left circle and the window background color can be seen through the right circle (which is translucent).

Now, when I draw the right circle, I want to clear this position first and then draw it, so that the desktop can be seen through the right circle. How should I achieve this?

Comment: To be clear, you want the intersection to be also transluscent? Or should the intersection bere moved all together?

Comment: Yes, it's still translucent, when I want to draw the circle on the right, first clear all the colors in the circle, and then draw the circle, rather than directly covering it

Comment: You can't draw a hole. You can build a geometry with a hole and draw it using D2D1_COMBINE_MODE_XOR/D2D1_COMBINE_MODE_EXCLUDE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-combine-geometries

Comment: Well, it turns out that I can't draw holes directly, no wonder I couldn't find a relevant tutorial. Thank you!